# Javascript timer - check how long left

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm trying to get the value of the timer in javascript, so it says something different when the timer is at zero;

```
var local_t = new Date();
local_t.setSeconds(local_t.getSeconds() + 60);
$('#local_clock').countdown(local_t, function(event) {
    if (local_t.getSeconds()==0) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('TIMER IS UP'));
        } else {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('Time Left: %M:%S'));
        }
    });
```

I've tried several variations on the `if (local_t.getSeconds()==0)` but can't work out how to do it.

Comment: What is `countdown()`? Where is that code?

Comment: @ScottMarcus http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Answer (score 2):

`event` contains valuable information. Use that instead of `local_t.getSeconds()`, because jQuery doesn't update that object, it only uses it to set the timer.

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Use `event.elapsed`, which is either `true` or `false`, `true` when countdown is done and now counting up.

Example:

```
var local_t = new Date();
local_t.setSeconds(local_t.getSeconds() + 60);

$('#local_clock').countdown(local_t, {elapse: true})
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        if (event.elapsed) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('TIMER IS UP'));
        } else {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('Time Left: %M:%S'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've just replaced my code with this and now it's not working on the page, looks like a js error somewhere?